# Парсинг Python. Как выполнить пагинацию и сохранить результат?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Продолжаю изучать парсинг. В качестве подопытного сайта выбрал вот такой интернет магазин:
[Сайт для обучения](https://oboi.ua/wallpaper/)

Решил делать этот и последующие в 2 этапа:

1. Селеном проходить все преграды, если такие возникнут и получать html файл.
2. Парсить html с помощью bs и requests.

Selen в данном случае прост, как двери:

```
from selenium import webdriver    

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r"D:\Python_lern\Project_new_oboi     \chromedriver.exe")

url = 'https://oboi.ua/wallpaper/'

driver.get(url)

page = driver.page_source

with open('page.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(page)
    file.close()

driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Получил ХТМЛ файл.И дальше получаю данные:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import csv

#Получаем ссылки на модели
# host = 'https://oboi.ua'
#
# all_links = []
#
# with open('page.html', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
#     contents = f.read()
#     for i in range(0, 1):
#         r = requests.get(url)
#         soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'lxml')
#
#         boxes = soup.find_all('div', class_='col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 c compare-del-parent')
#         for i in boxes:
#             links = host + i.find('a', class_='u').get('href')
#             all_links.append(links)
#
#     with open('all_links.txt', 'a') as f:
#         for line in all_links:
#             f.write(f'{line}\n')

#Парсим данные внутри карточки
with open('all_links.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
     data = []
     for line in lines:
        q = requests.get(line)
        res = q.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')

        model = soup.find('div', class_='view-products').find('h1').text
        brand =  soup.find('td', class_='col-xs-8').text
        country = soup.find('td', class_='col-xs-8').find('b').find_next('b').text
        article = soup.find(id='thiscode').text
        size = soup.find\
             (class_='table table-striped table-bord-bottom table-condensed').find_all('td') [8].find_next().text
         type = soup.find\
            (class_='table table-striped table-bord-bottom table-condensed').find_all('td')[10].find_next().text
         price = soup.find('span', class_='order-table-cost').text
         img = soup.find\
            ('div', class_='col-sm-3 col-md-5 col-lg-6').find(class_='img-responsive img-thumbnail').get('src')

        data.append(
            {
                'model':model,
                'brand':brand,
                'country':country,
                'article':article,
                'size':size,
                'type':type,
                'price':price,
                'img':img
            }
        )

#На этом этапе должен записываться файл
with open('all_models.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerow(['Model', 'Brand', 'Country', 'Article', 'Size', 'Type', 'Price', 'Img'])
    for line in lines:
        writer.writerow([soup['model'], soup['brand'], soup['country'], soup['article'], soup['size'], soup['type'], soup['price'], soup['img']])
```

вот на этом этапе возникает затруднение в сохранении всех данных в csv. В таком виде код создает файл только с заголовками. и с ошибкой "KeyError: 'model'".

Возникает 2 вопроса:

1. как корректно записать файл ?
2. как пройти пагинацию на данном сайте ? Желательно реализовать в блоке Селена. Но в данном случае не получается ни Селеном ни bs-ом. Xpath, CSS разные на кнопке "Далее" постоянно. По ID тоже не получается. В цикле так же не выходит, так как url всех страниц одинаковый.

Comment: После танцев с бубнами реализовал пагинацию через While True -> click() -> break. Но вылезла другая проблема, сохраняет в HTML файл только последнюю страницу, а не все в цикле. Как реализовать, чтоб при пагинации в файл собирались все страницы ?

Comment: Давать разное название файлу? Как вариант можно прикрепить к счетчику.